# Is 'Git Bash' classified as a virtual machine?

Tags: bash, virtual-machine, emulation

Is [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/) classified as a virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Git-Bash is not an emulator nor a virtual machine (WSL is, AFAIK). It's a [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porting) — software, written for Linux (and Unix in general) and compiled to run **natively** on w32.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no this is not a virtual machine, this is an emulator.

based on [this](https://appuals.com/what-is-git-bash/)

> In Windows, we tend to run commands in CMD but they are actually
> executable files that exist in the C:\Windows\System32 folder. The
> same case is for bash, it requires the utilities to make the commands
> work. In Unix systems, these utilities will be under /usr/bin
> directory. So, by installing the Git Bash these utilities will be
> installed in C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin folder.

This program actually installs commands that are created for windows runtime and used as in linux.

Comment: I agree that it is not a virtual machine, but I don't see how / why you call it an "emulator".   (An emulator of what?)  It is simply a collection of software tools that have been ported to run on Windows.  As the text you quoted says.

Comment: OK ... I see that https://gitforwindows.org/ describes git-bash as a "BASH emulation".  But that's not the same thing as an emulator ... in the sense that that term is normally used.